# includesvg: automatic generated .pdf and .pdf_tex files vs. quotation marks

Tags: svg

I want to include a .svg-file, which contains a excel-table, which i exported to an pdf.file and imported it into inkscape. I am using a few quotation marks (") in the excel-table and after importing the .pdf-file into inkscape everything looks fine. In Latex i am using the package {svg} for auto generating the .pdf and .pdf-tex files. The problem is that all the qotation marks are not getting escaped (i can see that in the .pdf_tex file). How can i resolve that problem?

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,titlepage,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=4cm, right=2cm, top=4cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{trimspaces}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\pdfminorversion=7
\definecolor{darkblack}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, breaklinks=true, linkcolor=darkblack, menucolor=darkblack, urlcolor=darkblack}
\usepackage{times}
\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\fontsize{4}{6}\selectfont
\includesvg[width=\textwidth]{Literaturrecherche.svg}
\caption[Ergebnisse Literaturrecherche]{Ergebnisse Literaturrecherche}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Example part of the .pdf_tex file:

```
\put(0.17426477,1.49716511){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}bitcoin) AND ("social \end{tabular}}}}%
\put(0.17426477,1.47727188){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}media" OR "soziale \end{tabular}}}}%
\put(0.17426477,1.45737864){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}Medien" OR facebook OR \end{tabular}}}}%
```

Comment: you haven't posted the relevant code to let anyone see the issue, which quotation marks need to be escaped?

Comment: take a look at the example part of the .pdf-tex file, sorry for that

Comment: so that should work without error, `"` doesn't need to be escaped in tex. If you mean that you want typographic left and right quotes it would be easiest to do that in the original source.

Comment: oh you have german babel enabled, use the babel  command to locally turn off the `"` shorthand at the point that you input the data

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: I don't use German babel much:-) something like `\shorthandoff{"}`

Comment: \shorthandoff{"} was the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally `"` would not cause an error but as you are using babel's german option it sets up `"` as a shorthand character to access accent and other commands.

So you can use

```
\shorthandoff{"}
```

to locally disable this while inputting the svg derived tex.

That will make it work without error but `"foo"` will produce ”foo”  so you may in any case prefer to edit the generated tex (or change the original source) to use

```
``foo''
```

and so get left and right quotes  “foo”